# Duplicate record in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hello freinds,

When I inserted data store duplicate data how can i resolve it Problem is like if i store name xyz in database stored by two times xyz Any budy have idea to resolve my problem

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what is the problem and what have you tried. Please refer to [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask questions.

Comment: This is not a problem, SQL cannot read your mind and know that you don't want duplicates. Right click on table -> design -> check "unique" on whatever column you don't want duplicates. I also removed the asp.net tag (not relevant in this context)

Answer (score 2):

Define a `UNIQUE` constraint on the table, eg

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_unq UNIQUE (columnName)
```

In this way, you can guarantee that the values of the `columnName` are all distinct. If you try to insert a value that already exist on that column, an excpetion will be thrown.

Comment: `tb_unq` is the name of the constraint. You can use this if you want to drop a constraint on the database.

Comment: No don't want to add constarint so how can i write above statement

Comment: if you don't want to create a constraint, you will use two statements the will check if it exist then insert or throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can check:

```
if((select count(*) From TableName Where name='xyz')=0)
Begin
 -- Insert code here.
End
```

Hope this will help.